# ansible \ include of other yml doesn't work

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

playbooks>
 all.yml
 tagger.yml
 configservice.yml

all.yml includes the other ymls in its script, but it fails.

all

```
  ---
  - name: build all dockers
    hosts: all  
    vars:      
        version1: "1.0"

    tasks:            

      - name: build all docker
        include: ./{{ item }}.yml
        with_items:
          - tagger
```

tagger

```
    ---
  - name: build tagger docker 
    hosts: all 
    tasks:
    - name: some step !!!!!!
      command: echo 1
```

example of tagger:

error

> TASK [build all docker] ********************************************************
>   fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "reason": "no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path.\n\nThe error appears to have been in './Build/plays/tagger.yml': line 2, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n---\n  - name: build tagger docker\n    ^ here\n\n\nThe error appears to have been in './Build/plays/tagger.yml': line 2, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n---\n  - name: build tagger docker\n    ^ here\n"}
>   }

seems like if I dismiss the "tasks:" from the child, it works, but I can't do it - I want the child to be independent..

Answer (score 0):

Actually your structure is a bit awkward, what you can do is put this as a role

roles/playbook_name/all.yml , tagger.yml configservice.yml

now in all.yml

```
---
  - name: build all dockers
    hosts: all  
    vars:      
        version1: "1.0"
  - name: call tagger
    host: all
    include: tagger.yml   #u can loop also with_items
```

in tagger

```
---
  - name: some step !!!!!!
    command: echo 1
```

And you can call this whole role by a wrapper from outside.

Comment: since I build dockers in those jobs, the relative folders went insane when I put things in role\tasks\main but activated all docker building from outside..wanted to avoid relative references..now I put everything in plays. Since this is not the deployment - only the docker building - would like to make it simple